# nifi check: attribute value match

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to write a EL in an update attribute processor. Below is my requirement:

User Input: IP Address
Storing in attribute: `target.host.name.linux`

I've another set of attributes defined in nifi.properties as:

```
trigger.target.system.linux.name=10.44.245.33
trigger.target.system.linux.password=Passw0rd
```

I'm trying to compare the user entered value with the attribute value present in properties file. If they match, I'll assign the variable above `trigger.target.system.linux.password` in the true condition or else publish 'no match'

Below are some EL I tried but in vain:

```
    ${${target.host.name.linux:equals(${trigger.target.system.linux.name})}:ifElse(${trigger.target.system.linux.password},'no match')}

${${'target.host.name.linux':equals(${'trigger.target.system.linux.name'})}:ifElse(${'trigger.target.system.linux.password'},'no match')}

${${${target.host.name.linux}:equals(${trigger.target.system.linux.name})}:ifElse(${trigger.target.system.linux.password},'no match')}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this EL in the UpdateAttribute processor:

```
Key: target.host.name.linux
Value: ${target.host.name.linux:equals(${trigger.target.system.linux.name}):ifElse(${trigger.target.system.linux.password},'no-match')}
```

**Illustration:**

**Entries in properties file**

[image]

**Test flow to check EL**
[image]

**UpdateAttribute processor**
[image]

**User enters matching value (User-Entry step)**
[image]

**UpdateAttribute EL result**
[image]

**User enters non-matching value (User-Entry step)**
[image]

**UpdateAttribute EL result**
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jagrut. Although your answer explains what I needed but on the same quest, is there some way I can hide the password to not appear in the flow file?

Comment: You can load an encrypted password and decrypt at the application-side that is going to read and use it. Also, as reference info, the `UpdateAttribute` processor has a `Delete Attributes Expression` property which will drop this attribute from the flow file - you can use this at some point in the flow when password is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

The `nifi.properties` file isn't a good location for custom property definitions -- it is used by the application framework for configuration but isn't designed to accept arbitrary values.

For your use case, you should take advantage of the [Variable Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Variables_Window) feature of Apache NiFi, which allows you to define custom variables and reference them in Expression Language clauses. In this case, defining the two variables in the registry and then using a `RouteOnAttribute` processor to route to one or another `UpdateAttribute` processors depending on the match (this approach removes the nested EL `ifElse` expressions; if you're comfortable with them, you can stick with the `UpdateAttribute` approach suggested by Jagrut).

Comment: Thanks Andy, I wasn't aware of the variable registry. Let me try it out.